# I need to add values of n columns but column values can be numeric but also alphabetic like AB,CD,EF,GH

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to add values of n columns, example of 3 columns is given below

```
SLNO    C1  C2  C3  Output
ROW1    10  10  AB  20
ROW2    10  AB  AB  10
ROW3    AB  AB  10  10
ROW4    AB  10  10  20
ROW5    AB  10  AB  10
ROW6    10  AB  10  20
ROW7    AB  AB  AB  AB
ROW8    10  10  10  30
```

Any Column value can either be numeric value or special values.
Special values like AB,CD,EF,GH

I need to build a query which will add these 3 or n columns and provide SUM in output columns.
I am having trouble in adding numeric value with alphabetic value like 10 + AB.

Can you please help be make a query or function or anything which will help me to add n columns with numeric and alphabetic entries.

if all columns are alphabetic like row slno 7, then output will be any column value

if we have 3 columns and 2 out of which have numeric value and rest 1 have alphabetic value, then we will add those 2 numeric values and ignore the alphabetic value or treat it like numeric value 0.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve - it's not obvious what the right answer to (10 + AB) should be. Thanks.

Comment: Needing to sum across columns is perhaps a sign of poor table design.  But storing numeric and character data in the same column is definitely bad design, how did you end up with this?

Comment: @rwp The OP wants to ignore in this case, or replace with zero.

Comment: Related: [Convert varchar value to int without throwing an exception in case of bad input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924272/convert-varchar-value-to-int-without-throwing-an-exception-in-case-of-bad-input)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `TRY_PARSE` like following.

```
SELECT *,
    ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(C1 AS INT),0) 
  + ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(C2 AS INT),0) 
  + ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(C3 AS INT),0) AS [Output]
 FROM [Table_Name]
```

**Example**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(SLNO VARCHAR(10), C1 VARCHAR(10)
                    , C2 VARCHAR(10), C3 VARCHAR(10)) 

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('ROW1', '10', '10', 'AB'), 
('ROW2','10', 'AB', 'AB' ), 
('ROW3', 'AB', 'AB', '10' ), 
('ROW4', 'AB', '10', '10' ), 
('ROW5', 'AB', '10', 'AB'), 
('ROW6', '10', 'AB', '10'), 
('ROW7', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB'), 
('ROW8', '10', '10', '10' ) 
SELECT *, 
 ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(C1 AS INT), 0) + 
 ISNULL(TRY_PARSE (C2 AS INT), 0) + 
 ISNULL(TRY_PARSE (C3 AS INT), 0) AS [Output] 
FROM @TABLE
```

**Output**

```
+------+----+----+----+--------+
| SLNO | C1 | C2 | C3 | Output |
+------+----+----+----+--------+
| ROW1 | 10 | 10 | AB | 20     |
+------+----+----+----+--------+
| ROW2 | 10 | AB | AB | 10     |
+------+----+----+----+--------+
| ROW3 | AB | AB | 10 | 10     |
+------+----+----+----+--------+
| ROW4 | AB | 10 | 10 | 20     |
+------+----+----+----+--------+
| ROW5 | AB | 10 | AB | 10     |
+------+----+----+----+--------+
| ROW6 | 10 | AB | 10 | 20     |
+------+----+----+----+--------+
| ROW7 | AB | AB | AB | 0      |
+------+----+----+----+--------+
| ROW8 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 30     |
+------+----+----+----+--------+
```

Edit :

> Row7 needs to reflect output as AB as all columns are AB

Not sure what will happen if the colum values are like 'AB','AB',BC'

Still you can try like following.

```
SELECT SLNO,C1,C2,C3,
(
  CASE WHEN [Output] =0 THEN C1
  ELSE CAST([Output] AS VARCHAR(100))
  END
) AS [Output]

FROM

(
    SELECT *, 
     ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(C1 AS INT), 0) + 
     ISNULL(TRY_PARSE (C2 AS INT), 0) + 
     ISNULL(TRY_PARSE (C3 AS INT), 0) AS [Output] 
    FROM @TABLE 
) T
```

**[DEMO](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=82e7e27b974f114eda7b7c31acc52528)**

Comment: Row7 needs to reflect output as AB as all columns are AB

Comment: @RaghuveerDevrajShetty Why are you using this bad table design?  As a rule of thumb, _don't_ mix numeric and text data in the same column.

Comment: @RaghuveerDevrajShetty consider accepting the answer if it resolved your query

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `apply`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce( convert(varchar(255), sumint), max_origval) as the_sum
from t cross apply
     (select sum(intval) as sum_int, max(origval) as max_origval 
      from (values (try_convert(int, c1), c1),
                   (try_convert(int, c2), c1),
                   (try_convert(int, c3), c1)
           ) v(intval, origval);
```

`sum()` only returns `NULL` if all the values are `NULL`.  From the description of your problem, this will only occur if all values are non-numeric.